# ssh2_exec execution stops after 32kb of data

Tags: php, ssh, php-7.0

I am using the php ssh2 methods to establish a connection to a server and transmit a string of ~39Kb. However, after 32Kb the transmission stops with an exception:

```
ErrorException: ssh2_exec(): Unable to request command execution on remote host in /var/www/xxx/xxxSSH.php:36
```

Is there an artificial limit on how many bytes can be transmitted in a session and if so, how can I change the limit?

**UPDATE**

Here's the method producing the error:

```
public function exec($cmd)
    {
    if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($this->connection, $cmd))) {
        throw new Exception('SSH command failed');
    }

    stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
    $data = "";
    while ($buf = fread($stream, 4096)) {
        $data .= $buf;
    }
    fclose($stream);
    return $data;
}
```

`$cmd` contains the string that seems to cause the trouble. What it does is call `echo '$extremelyLongString' > /etc/someconfig.cfg`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code from your php script, and indicate which line of code is producing the error. It would also be helpful to know something about the remote command that you're executing, notably whether it produces any output and how much.

Comment: did you tried to increase your memory limit, time limit or stream timeout?